# Between Drupal and node.js, which one is better (fit in) to develop Jobs Board Application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, drupal, web-applications, jobs

My question is: To developed an advanced Jobs Board Application, you recommend me to use a CMS as Drupal or node.js based development.

Many thnaks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

This question is seriously lacking in detail.

Drupal is a CMS and Node js is a framework. In theory, you could build a website with Drupal and not code anything, the same cannot be said for Node.

Using Drupal will make development faster and should have all the functionality you need when extended with modules.

Node will supply a completely custom solution. However, you will need to think about ever singe element, user authentication ect...